# How to exlude word using Regex?

Tags: javascript, regex, pattern-matching, firefox-addon, webrequest

I try the code below, the goal is block all image of third partie using own firefox addon

So, for example :
If I open *www.test.com* page, I agree to see all image from the active domain (*www.test.com*) but I want to **block all other image** (*www.boring-ads.com, www.iamthebest.net,...*)

```
var MyPattern= /^((?!goodimg\.net).)*$/ig;

function cancel(requestDetails) {
   //console.log("Canceling: " + requestDetails.url);
   return {cancel: true};
}

browser.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
   cancel,
   {urls: [MyPattern], types: ["image"]},
   ["blocking"]
);
```

All image from *goodimg.net* are loaded,  **but already from other domain** :(((

Why ? ...isn't possible to exclude a string using regex ?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. At present, your question is not very clear and it's not easy for us to help you. The title of the question `why regex no match exclusion?` is confusing, as well as the rest of the question. Clarify what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Firefox (or chrome) don't use RegEx to check url, 
Please read [Match_patterns](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Match_patterns)
You can send your pattern match:

```
/^(\*|http|https|ws|wss|file|ftp):\/\/(\*|(?:\*\.)?(?:[^\/*]+))?\/(.*)$/
```

[matchPatternToRegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Match_patterns#Match_pattern_structure)

You can use `<all_urls>` and url inside mothod `cancel`